# bash escaping quotes

Tags: bash, scripting, quoting, escape-characters

I have an interesting challenge for how to escape quotes in a bash script.

My bash script has a long curl call with a large -d json structure passed.

```
#!/bin/bash

Value4Variable=Value4

curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d  \
'{"Variable1":"Value1", 
"Variable2":"Value2\'s",  # escape of quote doesnt work because of the previous single quote and backslash
"Variable3":"Value3",
"Variable4":"'"$Value4Variable"'", 
"Variable5":"Value5"
}' \
https://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php
```

What's the best way to add a single quote into the json structure? I've tried various combinations but no success.

Comment: The same way you used for expanding the variable. End the single-quotes, insert a single-quote (either quoted or escaped), then start the single-quoted string again. So `'....'\''....'` or `'....'"'"'....'`

Comment: Why not put the JSON into a data file, and use `curl [...] --data @mydata.json`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti there is a variable that needs to be expanded inside the json - it won't be expanded inside a file without extra work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to escape long strings with different quotes. The simplest is to end the single quote and escape the single quote:

```
'...'\''...'
```

But there are some nicer things you can do. Heredocs are a good way to avoid the quoting issue:

```
curl -s -X POST https://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -d  @- <<EOF
{
    "Variable1":"Value1", 
    "Variable2":"Value2's",
    "Variable3":"Value3",
    "Variable4":"$Value4Variable", 
    "Variable5":"Value5"
}
EOF
```

`@-` tell curl to read from stdin and `<<EOF` starts the heredoc which will be feed into the stdin of curl. The nice thing with the heredoc is that you do not need to escape any quotes and can use bash variables inside them sidestepping the need to worry about how to escape the quotes and making the whole thing much more readable.

Comment: Thanks. The EOF is a really nice approach. I've used it before with ftp commands but I didn't strike the connection that I can use it in curl too.

Comment: and you can use any string not just `EOF`, so you could use `EOF17493IBetThisWontBeInTheDoc48uth549uthud492` or better something random.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `--data @filename` notation to read the data from file:

Sample `json-data-file` contents:

```
{"Variable1":"Value1", 
"Variable2":"Value2's",
"Variable3":"Value3",
"Variable4":"'$Value4Variable'", 
"Variable5":"Value5"
}
```

---

The request:

```
Value4Variable="Value4"
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" \
-d @<(sed "s/\$Value4Variable/$Value4Variable/" json-data-file) \
https://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php/test123
```

The output:

```
The POSTed value is:

********************

{"Variable1":"Value1", "Variable2":"Value2's","Variable3":"Value3","Variable4":"'Value4'", "Variable5":"Value5"}

********************

Results saved to: test123
*Note: Results are purged periodically. 1 hr minimum life.
```

Comment: Thanks! This works although I prefer to have it all in one file as there are multiple curls in the script and splitting them all into different files makes maintenance a bit more convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a JSON-aware tool to create JSON documents.  Doing so would remove the need to manually escape special characters like tabs, newline, double quotes etc.  A single quote is actually a character that *doesn't* need to be escaped in JSON.  You just need to make sure you're using the correct quotes for the shell to recognize your string properly.

The `jo` tool [from here](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/) is made to make creating JSON documents from the command line be really easy:

```bsh
somevariable2='line1
line2
line3'

curl -s -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -d "$( jo \
        variable1="Value1" \
        variable2="$somevariable2" \
        variable3='String with "quotes"' \
        variable4="It's raining!" \
        variable5='\/\/\/\/\/' )" \
    'https://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php'
```

or

```bsh
somevariable2='line1
line2
line3'

jo \
    variable1="Value1" \
    variable2="$somevariable2" \
    variable3='String with "quotes"' \
    variable4="It's raining!" \
    variable5='\/\/\/\/\/' |
curl -s -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -d @- \
    'https://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php'
```

The response for either piece of code is

```
The POSTed value is:

********************

{"variable1":"Value1","variable2":"line1\nline2\nline3","variable3":"String with \"quotes\"","variable4":"It's raining!","variable5":"/\\/\\/\\/\\/"}

********************
```